# Is it possible to switch off CuDNN in keras\tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cudnn

Is it possible to switch off CuDNN in keras\tensorflow? Or is it possible to install keras\tensorflow without CuDNN(as far as I know in anaconda CuDNN is installed by default)?

Comment: The CPU-only builds of Tensorflow do not require cuDNN. If you want to go for the GPU version, though, everything prebuilt is built against some version of cuDNN. It *might* be possible to disable it at compile time, but from what I remember the GPU build instructions require you to install cuDNN so I'm not too sure that's doable.

Answer (score -2):

You can make specific layers (or the entire model) use only the CPU like this:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    #declare your model's layers here
```

Comment: No, I need GPU support, but without CuDNN.